# counting duplicates in a sorted sequence using command line tools

Tags: bash, command-line, sorting, count, duplicates

I have a command (cmd1) that greps through a log file to filter out a set of numbers. The numbers are 
in random order, so I use sort -gr to get a reverse sorted list of numbers. There may be duplicates within 
this sorted list. I need to find the count for each unique number in that list.

For e.g. if the output of cmd1 is:

```
100 
100 
100 
99 
99 
26 
25 
24 
24
```

I need another command that I can pipe the above output to, so that, I get:

```
100     3
99      2
26      1
25      1
24      2
```

Comment: related: http://serverfault.com/questions/37020/counting-duplicates-in-a-sorted-sequence-using-command-line-tools

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16980265/32453

Answer (score 118, accepted):

how about;

```
$ echo "100 100 100 99 99 26 25 24 24" \
    | tr " " "\n" \
    | sort \
    | uniq -c \
    | sort -k2nr \
    | awk '{printf("%s\t%s\n",$2,$1)}END{print}'
```

The result is :

```
100 3
99  2
26  1
25  1
24  2
```

Comment: I ran this and it produced an extra print statement of $1,$2 at the end: `100 3 99 2 26 1 25 1 24 2       2 24`

Comment: The following adds a new line between the results and removes the extra line at the end:  `echo "100 100 100 99 99 26 25 24 24" | tr " " "\n" | sort | uniq -c | sort -k2nr | awk '{printf("%s\t%s\n",$2,$1)}END{print}' | head -n -1` so you get: `100 3
99 2
26 1
25 1
24 2
`

Comment: Note about syntax, you can end a line with a pipe instead of using a backslash.

Comment: Note about note regarding syntax: that's absolutely true and "cleaner", _however_ in shell scripts (and SQL fwiw), I've evolved a personal preference (after trying both) preferring "pipe first", as (for me) it's visually easier to see _"hey, this is a pipe."_  (Likewise in SQL blocks, I put my semi-colon line terminators at the beginning of the subsequent line.)

Comment: there's currently an extraneous `END{print}` that prints out an extra copy of the last line of input. To print a blank line, it should have been `END{print "\n"}` or just get rid of it altogether, e.g., `cmd1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -k2nr | awk '{printf("%s\t%s\n",$2,$1)}'` or for the `awk` part even just `awk 'OFS="\t" { print $2, $1 }'`

Answer (score 69):

`uniq -c` works for GNU uniq 8.23 at least, and does exactly what you want (assuming sorted input).

Comment: in case if the input is not sorted, then just add `sort` command: `sort file_name | uniq -c `

Comment: Awesome. Works on Mac OS X as well! Tested on Mojave 10.14.6.

Answer (score 11):

if order is not important

```
# echo "100 100 100 99 99 26 25 24 24" | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)a[$i]++}END{for(o in a) printf "%s %s ",o,a[o]}'
26 1 100 3 99 2 24 2 25 1
```

Comment: +1 for doing this with 3 less pipes.  It would be awesome if you could elaborate on how this works b/c it confused me. ;-)   Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Numerically sort the numbers in reverse, then count the duplicates, then swap the left and the right words. Align into columns.

```
printf '%d\n' 100 99 26 25 100 24 100 24 99 \
   | sort -nr | uniq -c | awk '{printf "%-8s%s\n", $2, $1}'
```

```
100     3
99      2
26      1
25      1
24      2
```

Answer (score 2):

In Bash, we can use an **associative array** to count instances of each input value.  Assuming we have the command `$cmd1`, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

cmd1='printf %d\n 100 99 26 25 100 24 100 24 99'
```

Then we can count values in the array variable `a` using the `++` mathematical operator on the relevant array entries:

```
while read i
do
    ((++a["$i"]))
done < <($cmd1)
```

We can print the resulting values:

```
for i in "${!a[@]}"
do
    echo "$i ${a[$i]}"
done
```

---

If the order of output is important, we might need an external `sort` of the keys:

```
for i in $(printf '%s\n' "${!a[@]}" | sort -nr)
do
    echo "$i ${a[$i]}"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you have input stored in *my_file* you can do:

```
sort -nr my_file | uniq -c | awk ' { t = $1; $1 = $2; $2 = t; print; } '
```

Otherwise just pipe the input to be processed to the same cmd.

Explanation:

- `sort -nr` sorts the input numerically (`-n`) in reverse order (`-r`)
- `uniq -c` count duplicates and shows the count side-by-side
- `awk '{ t = $1; $1 = $2; $2 = t; print; }'` swaps the two columns

Answer (score 0):

Ruby internally has tools to do this very efficiently from the command line.

Example, given this file:

```
$ cat file
100 
100 
100 
99 
99 
26 
25 
24 
24
1
```

1. Count each;
2. Sort by a) decreasing occurrence b) decreasing value;
3. Put in lined up columns.

This Ruby does that:

```
ruby  -e '
cnt=Hash.new(0)
$<.each{|x| cnt[x.to_i]+=1}
w1,w2=cnt.max_by{|e| e.to_s.length}.map{|e| e.to_s.length+2}
cnt.sort_by{|k,v| [-v,-k]}.each{|k,v| 
            puts "#{k.to_s.rjust(w1," ")}\t#{v.to_s.rjust(w2," ")}"
}' file
```

Prints:

```
  100     3
   99     2
   24     2
   26     1
   25     1
    1     1
```

The input file does not need to be sorted.