# calculate count of char use in string

Tags: string, bash

I'm trying to make this program work and I can't, The script i want must should calculate count of char use in string 
example :
string=good
result=g1o2d1
is there any way to write script that calculate exactly count of string like my example or not ?

```
 #!/bin/bash
    string=ssstttrrrriiiinnnnngg
    z=$( for((i=0;i<${#string};i++)) do; echo ${string:i:1}; done | uniq -c )
    echo $z
```

---

my result :

```
s 3 t 3 r 4 i 4 n 5 g 2
```

but for analysis some document i want script to calculate char some like 
firstchar1=$( bash script )
......
i need that value for use another script 
please advise me 
regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ echo "abaaacdefg" | grep -o .
a
b
a
a
a
c
d
e
f
g

$ echo "abaaacdefg" | grep -o .| sort
a
a
a
a
b
c
d
e
f
g

$  echo "abaaacdefg" | grep -o .| sort |  uniq -c 
      4 a
      1 b
      1 c
      1 d
      1 e
      1 f
      1 g


$ echo "abaaacdefg" | grep -o .| sort |  uniq -c | awk '{printf $2$1}'
a4b1c1d1e1f1g1
```

See 
[Bash: Split string into character array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7578930/bash-split-string-into-character-array) and 
[counting duplicates in a sorted sequence using command line tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092405/counting-duplicates-in-a-sorted-sequence-using-command-line-tools)