# How to get the number of different lines in bash

Tags: bash, shell

Say I have a test output generated by `cat some_file | grep some_text`, and the output is like the following:

```
some text: 123123
some text: 123123
some text: 123123
some text: 123123
some text: 345345
some text: 123123
some text: 345345
some text: 345345
```

I want to have a summary of each line's frequency from this text like:

```
some text: 345345 => 3
some text: 123123 => 5
```

How to do that in bash?

Comment: Does "some text" change?  ie, do you want to aggregate on the final column?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092405/counting-duplicates-in-a-sorted-sequence-using-command-line-tools

Comment: You probably just want `... | sort | uniq -c`